# No logro guardar nombre de imagen en mi tabla

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Intento hacer un *upload* de imágenes, el cual la imagen si me la sube a la ruta especificada, pero también quiero guardar el nombre de la imagen en la tabla el cual no me lo guarda.

Ya le hice un: `var_dump("$logotipo");` el cual me aparece vacio: `string(0) ""`

Este es el formulario de donde subo la imagen:

```
<form id="regiration_form" action="procesamientos/recibedatos.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">             
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label class="text-success" for="log">Logotipo</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="log" name="logotipo" accept="image/*" required> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Y este es el archivo que se encarga de subir la imagen al servidor, y grabar el  nombre de la imagen:

recibedatos.php:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$dbname = "mi_bd";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$logotipo= $_POST["logotipo"];

$uploadedfileload="true"; 
$uploadedfile_size=$_FILES['logotipo']['size'];
 echo $_FILES['logotipo']['name'];
 if ($_FILES['logotipo']['size']>200000) {
$msg=$msg."El archivo es mayor que 200KB, debes reduzcirlo antes de subirlo<BR>"; 
$uploadedfileload="false";
}
 if (!($_FILES['logotipo']['type'] =="image/jpeg" OR $_FILES['logotipo']['type'] =="image/gif")) 
{
$msg=$msg." Tu archivo tiene que ser JPG o GIF. Otros archivos no son permitidos<BR>"; 
$uploadedfileload="false";
}
 $file_name=$_FILES['logotipo']['name'];
 $add=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/farmaciayanalisis/imagenes/farmacia/$file_name"; 
if($uploadedfileload=="true"){ 
if(move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['logotipo']['tmp_name'], $add))
{
 //Si la imagen es la correcta se inserta los datos en la tabla.
$sql= "INSERT INTO datos(logotipo)
VALUES ($logotipo')";
}else{
echo "Error al subir el archivo";
}
 }else{
echo $msg;
}


if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Datosinsertados correctamente";
} else {
  echo "Error al registrar Datos: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás intentando asignar a la variable `$logotipo` la variable `$_POST['logotipo']`, pero esto no es así.

Cuando envías un archivo mediante el formulario, tienes que acceder al mismo mediante `$_FILES`. Fíjate, que de hecho en tu código, para guardar la imagen en el servidor, comprobar el tipo de archivo etc, estás usando `$_FILES` y no `$_POST`.

Para obtener el nombre puedes utilizar:

```
$_FILES['logotipo']['name']
```

Lo cual ya estás haciendo más adelante al asignar dicho dato a `$file_name`.

Puedes ver más información de los datos de `$_FILES` con:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```